# Translate strings of 0's and 1's into lines of vectors for SVM Analysis

Tags: python

As a follow up to another question that was answered, I now have data in the following format:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Im looking for a python function (a for loop possibly) that achieves the following output:

```
34:1
27:1 33:1 36:1
20:1 32:1
```

Notice how the first digit, is the place it used to have in the 40 length long bit pattern. The second digit (after the colon) is the original number '1'.

Im new to python, and posting my questions here, has helped me so much in learning python. So if you have any idea how to do this please feel free to respond. Once again this is not homework, im attempting to create a sentiment analysis program, and i need this data format for SVM. The other format is made for TiMBL.

**EDIT**

As some of the lines contain only 0's. The output of the awesome :) answer down below, produces empty lines in the output text file. How do i add a function that prevents this from happening?
Or create a new function that reads the file, and deletes newlines? I have a feeling that will delete all of them, which might give me problems.

Comment: So is this data really binary or is it a string of ones and zeros?

Comment: @F.J my apologies for using the wrong terms. i changed the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> strs = """0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"""

>>> for x in strs.splitlines():                                                              
    print " ".join("{}:{}".format(i,1) for i,y in enumerate(x.split(), 1) if y=='1')
...     
34:1
27:1 33:1 36:1
20:1 32:1
```

For files:

```
>>> with open("abc") as f:
    for line in f:
        strs =  " ".join("{}:{}".format(i,1) for i,y in enumerate(line.split(), 1) if y=='1')
        if strs:
            print strs
...             
34:1
27:1 33:1 36:1
20:1 32:1
```

where `abc` contains:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: what if `strs = open("filname", "r+")` , splitlines will then not work, but taking away the `.splitlines()` will create the wrong output. I suspect because the way it reads the file, i have to do something extra, as each line in the file is equal to 1 string. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @RHK-S8 you can use a  simple `if` condition to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably reinventing the wheel.  Look around for libraries that do "sparse matrix" manipulations, and think about whether they will do what you need.

I don't know much about the problem you're solving, but if it's really a data analysis project rather than about producing a nice interface for solving such problems, and you have a bit of mathematical background, then languages like R or matlab might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, turn the problem on its head and serve up the input data as selectors to the [itertools.compress](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) function going against a sequence of integers starting with 1

```
import StringIO
from itertools import count, compress, imap
import contextlib
s = '''\
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0
'''
with contextlib.closing(StringIO.StringIO(s)) as f:
    for line in f:
            selectors = line.strip().split()
            selectors = imap(int, selectors)
            data = compress(count(1), selectors)
            print " ".join("{}:{}".format(x, 1) for x in data)

34:1
27:1 33:1 36:1
20:1 32:1
```